# Redirect user after confirming pop-up

Tags: react-router

I am trying to take a react-bootstrap `Button` object and make it such that, when clicked, it confirms the user's intent and then redirects them to another page if they say yes, or leaves them where they are if they say no.

The kicker is this site is actually all one `page` and clicking navigation menu items just loads different components, and I'm trying to do this without editing `window.location.href` directly.

`<li id="doThingsButton" ><Button onClick={() => { this.doThing(); }} >Do all the things!</Button></li>`

Here's the pseudo-code version of what `this.doThing()` does:

```
private doThing() {
    if (number > 10000) {
        if (confirm("Doing " + number + " things")) {
            this.okDoThing();
        }
    }
    else {
        this.okDoThing();
    } }
```

The confirmation part works just fine, it's the redirect-after-confirm I'm having trouble with.

I think I can use [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js) to accomplish this, but have yet to be successful at it. Any hints? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.assign("https://yoursite.com/redirection");`. This function loads a new document in your current window.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp